# access mongodb running inside docker + wsl2, on Host windows

Tags: mongodb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am running mongodb instance using docker-compose as docker container, which is running in a WSL2 environment on windows 10 machine.

[image]

From my host windows 10 machine, i am able to connect to nodejs container `http://localhost:3001/api/v1`, also using mongo-compass I can't connect to mongodb instance,

The error I get is `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`.

Please help, how can i connect to mongodb instance from host windows machine.

Comment: Your localhost won't be visible to the docker as `http://localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. You need to provide your IP address to connect

Comment: which ip address, my host windows m/c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to connect from your host machine to one of the docker container's ports you need to make sure this port is exposed to the host.

From what I can see on your screenshot, your containers configured is such a way, that only `node` container exposes `3001` port, therefore you can reach it from your host via localhost.

The problem with `mongo` occurs because your docker-compose configuration doesn't expose mongodb container's (named `mongo` on your screenshot) port `27017` to the host machine.

So to fix that, you need to set `ports`. As an example:

```yaml
...
services:
...
mongo:
  ...
  ports:
    - "27017"
...
```

Please note, you need to make sure 27017 are not used by any other service running on your host before exposing it. IF this port is busy and you don't want to stop the service, you can simply use another port on your host:

```yaml
...
mongo:
  ...
  ports:
    - "27018:27017"
...
```

More about docker-compose configs is [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ports).